# How can I make a table row slide out to display a list with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

There is a navbar on my website that utilizes html tables. Right now, I have an option on the bottom that displays a list. I have it so when you hover, the options pop out, but I would prefer that they slide out.

I know it's hard to animate table rows, and I would just like to know if this works. I have tried JQuery, and it works with `.slideToggle()` but when you go in and out of it a few times and leave your mouse out, it still bounces up and down and it looks awful. I would accept an answer that is truthfully telling me I can't achieve what I want.

Here is the code:

```html
<tr>
    <td class="row-dropdown">
       <div>
           Category<i class="caret" style="float:right;"></i>
       </div>
       <ul class="list">
            <hr class="list-divider">
            <li><a class="list-item" href="#">Opt. 1</a></li>
            <hr class="list-divider">
            <li><a class="list-item" href="#">Opt. 2</a></li>
            <hr class="list-divider">
            <li><a class="list-item" href="#">Opt. 3</a></li>
            <hr class="list-divider">
            <li><a class="list-item" href="#">Opt. 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my (minimal) CSS:

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.row-dropdown {
  /* Animation stuff will go here? */
}

.list {
  /* Animation stuff will go here? */
}

.row-dropdown:hover .list {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: "*There is a navbar on my website that utilizes html tables.*" on the assumption that your navigation is not tabular data, and that you're using the `<table>` for layout purposes, I'd suggest that this is your problem. Consider using `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `menu` elements rather than a `<table>`. Although having just double-checked thee information, at MDN, about the [`<menu>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu) element I retract that suggestion.

Comment: @DavidThomas Hey David! I just talked to my boss about it, and he agreed that it probably isn't a good idea either. I would, however, like a fix as it is now. It would just be temporary.

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob You mean the ```<hr>``` tag? It doesn't? I thought it did, I always see it that way. Either way it works, thanks I will keep this in mind though!

Comment: It "works" because browsers are attempting to accommodate web pages that used the closing slash thinking they would one day use XML and XHTML. However, [no HTML standard has ever specified the use of the closing slash](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element). The standard allows it but the slash does nothing, means nothing and browsers are instructed to ignore it. So it's useless and pointless to put it there.

Comment: @Rob that's good to know, however, is there any way you could answer my question? Mr. Bagel didn't help very much, LOL! And well, if it doesn't make a difference then I don't see why it matters, but that's just me I guess, I'll remove the slashes.

Comment: @Rob btw, I closed the tags because it's a React thing. You will get an error if you don't soft-close tags like br and hr. I just got it a little mixed up